# Magento Credit memo, changing ORDER-id to INVOICE-id

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

In Magento you can cancel an order or invoice, and set it to a creditmemo. This is working correctly, but in our case we need the INVOICE-id, instead of an ORDER-id. By default, Magento uses the INVOICE-id.

This isn't some "setting", but it would probably need to be coded by hand. That's not a problem for me, but I can't seem to find the right file to edit.

Does anyone know whether this is even possible? Or does someone else had this problem before?

Thanks in advance!

:( Can't seem to set a bounty, otherwise i would have done it.

Comment: [Bounties](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/set-bounties) are only available when you have 75 rep or more, and the question is more than 48 hours old.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an invoice ID, you can trivially retrieve the order ID of the order it is tied to.

```
$invoice = Mage::getModel("sales/order_invoice")->load($invoice_id);
$order_id = $invoice->getOrderId();
```

Hope that helps!

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: If this doesn't do it for you, can you give a little more detail about the context in which you want the order ID?

Comment: Hi Joe, thanks for your reply! We're going to dig into it, and let you know if this is the 'correct' answer. This **does** helps us, so you're getting a rep from me =)